# How to force a page to be displayed inside an ext:Panel?

Tags: ext.net

This is about `ext.net`.

I have a link in `West` section, by clicking which, a webpage should be displayed in the `Center` section in a tab. But how to prevent the page from being rendered in a new browser window or tab (by shift click, or right click, then pick open in a new tab)?

Comment: make it reference to a master-page, which forces the `<ext:panel>` you could also check the source code of http://examples.ext.net itself

Comment: sounds good. but how to force the `<ext:panel>` on the master-page? can you please post a link or something?

Comment: did... but i didn't do that myself, i just know there is a way to do this sorry ;) you might wanna google yourself right?

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest to use a LinkButton (if you really need your link to look as a link).
http://examples.ext.net/#/Buttons/Basic/LinkButton/

Handle its Click event and load any URL to the Center region.

```
App.PanelCenter.load({ url: "some URL" });
```

PanelCenter should be configured with a respective Loader.

Hope this helps.